# Prevent Browser File Caching

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache

I need to disable caching for single files in all browsers. 
I have a website that generates small video clips. There is a preview stage where the results can be watched.

An mp4 called *preview.mp4* is displayed. When the user goes back, edits the video and wants to preview it again, the old *preview.mp4* is being displayed even though the file on the server is changed.

How can I prevent the caching of this video file? Or what are the other ways to fix it?

**Note:** it's a single page application so I don't reload any HTML files. Only PHP content. Hence the headers I set, are not useful in this scenario:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers

Comment: I already use those. Please see updated questions.

Comment: What HTTP headers are being returned for the video?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the web page itself you should be concerned about, but the `mp4` file which is downloaded and cached separately.

Ensure the response headers of the `mp4` file prevent browser caching.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Answer (score 1):

> Hence the headers I set, are not useful in this scenario:
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
> ```

There problem here is that those are **not** headers.

They are HTML elements (which are part of the HTML document, which is the body of the HTTP response) which attempt to be equivalent to HTTP headers … and fail.

You need to set *real* HTTP headers, and you need to send them with the video file (rather than the HTML document).

The specifics of how you do that will depend on the HTTP server you use.

Further reading:

- [Caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13) in the HTTP specification
- [Caching Tutorial for Web Authors and Webmasters](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)
- [Caching Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/caching.html) in the Apache HTTPD manual
- [How to Modify the Cache-Control HTTP Header When You Use IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/247404)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a cache key

```
preview.mp4?cachekey=randNum
```

Where randNum can be a timestamp or you use a random number generator to generate randNum.